# Tagging bug?....

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

After trying four times to edit [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8334/chow-test-or-not) to add the "[change-point](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-point)" tag to it, which is associated with three existing questions, I have been unsuccessful: no matter how emphatically I type :-) it always gets converted to "[changepoint](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/changepoint)" *and this (unwanted) tag only links to the question itself!,* not to the other questions.  Something's wrong here.  Am I misunderstanding how the tagging is supposed to work?

Comment: Just so you know it is not only you, I just tried to retag and the same thing happened to me. It didn't even come up that I edited the tags.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like [change-point](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-point) is set up as synonym of [changepoint](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/changepoint).

https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=renames&filter=active

Comment: @Jeff But then synonyms aren't working correctly!

Comment: It was put in the wrong direction, that's all. Should be ok now, I have done the merge.

Comment: @mbq Thanks, but why does direction matter?  "Synonym of" is supposed to be a symmetric relation.  That seems still to be a bug...

Comment: @whu there can be only one winner. One has to remap to the other.

Comment: @whuber, Oops my bad. I introduced the changepoint tag, since I though that is the correct spelling of change-point. After I saw the mistake, I created a synonym, since I could not delete the tag. Or something to that effect, since this happened month or so ago, my memory is a bit vague on the details.

Comment: @Jeff There is no problem with the remapping: you are right, each equivalence class of synonyms needs a representative.  The problem is that *the lookup of questions with associated tags does not work.*  Thus the synonym feature is effectively broken.